# Cluster adjacent points

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have a sequence of xy planes with integer coordinates and each one has points scattered differently over it.

For each plane I would like perform clustering of the points, putting in the same cluster a point that is far from another point in the cluster by less than d (or exactly d).
For example if there is a point P1(x,y) in the cluster and d=1 also

- P2(x+1,y)
- P3(x,y+1)
- P4(x+1,y+1)
- P5(x-1,y)
- P6(x,y-1)
- P7(x-1,y-1)
- P8(x+1,y-1)
- P9(x-1,y+1)

will fall in the same cluster. Graphically:

```
P9   P3   P4    
   \ |  /
P5 - P1 - P2
   / |  \
P7   P6   P8
```

Which clustering algorithm is best suited for this task?

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much a clustering problem, but you have your neighbor relation,
and you want to compute the **[transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)** of this neighbor relation.

This is a much simpler problem, and it has an obvious and efficient straightforward solution ([breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)):

While there are unprocessed points:

1. Initialize a new empty result set.
2. Working set = choose any one (!) unprocessed point
3. While the working set is not empty:

   1. Add working set to result set
   2. Mark all points in the working set as processed
   3. Working set = all ''unprocessed'' neighbors of the previous working set
4. Return the result set as new group.

Comment: It seems somewhat disrespectful and contrary to the spirit of the site to claim that the problem has an "obvious and straightforward" solution and then not give that solution.